# выборка из базы данных учитывая массив

Tags: php, mysql

Есть 2 массива массивов, 1 с городами а 2 с категориями:

```
$cities = array(
        'Брестская область' => array(
           'Брест', 'Барановичи', 'Береза', 'Ганцевичи',
           'Дрогичин' ,'Жабинка' ,'Иваново', 'Ивацевичи',
           'Каменец' ,'Кобрин', 'Лунинец', 'Ляховичи',
           'Малорита' ,'Пинск', 'Пружаны', 'Столин',
           'Брестская область'),
        'Витебская область' => array(
           'Витебск','Бешенковичи', 'Браслав', 'Верхнедвинск',
           'Глубокое', 'Городок', 'Докшицы', 'Дубровно',
           'Лепель', 'Лиозно', 'Миоры', 'Орша', 'Полоцк',
           'Поставы', 'Россоны', 'Сенно', 'Толочин', 'Ушачи',
           'Чашники', 'Шарковщина', 'Шумилино', 'Витебская область'),
        'Гомельская область' => array(
           'Гомель', 'Брагин', 'Буда-Кошелево', 'Ветка',
           'Добруш', 'Ельск', 'Житковичи', 'Жлобин',
           'Калинковичи', 'Корма', 'Лельчицы', 'Лоев',
           'Мозырь', 'Наровля', 'Октябрьский', 'Петриков',
           'Речица', 'Рогачев', 'Светлогорск', 'Хойники',
           'Чечерск', 'Гомельская область'),
        'Гродненская область' => array(
           'Гродно', 'Берестовица', 'Волковыск', 'Вороново',
           'Дятлово', 'Зельва', 'Ивье', 'Кореличи',
           'Лида', 'Мосты', 'Новогрудок', 'Островец',
           'Ошмяны', 'Свислочь', 'Слоним', 'Сморгонь',
           'Щучин', 'Гродненская область'),
        'Минская область' => array(
           'Минск', 'Березино', 'Борисов', 'Вилейка',
           'Воложин', 'Дзержинск', 'Жодино', 'Клецк',
           'Копыль', 'Крупки', 'Логойск', 'Любань',
           'Марьина Горка', 'Молодечно', 'Мядель', 
           'Несвиж', 'Слуцк', 'Смолевичи', 'Солигорск', 
           'Старые Дороги', 'Столбцы', 'Узда',
           'Червень', 'Минская область'),
        'Могилёвская область' => array(
           'Могилев', 'Белыничи', 'Бобруйск', 'Быхов', 
           'Глуск', 'Горки', 'Дрибин', 'Кировск', 'Климовичи',
           'Кличев', 'Костюковичи', 'Краснополье', 'Кричев',
           'Круглое', 'Мстиславль', 'Осиповичи', 'Славгород', 
           'Хотимск', 'Чаусы', 'Чериков', 'Шклов', 'Могилёвская область')
      );

      $categors = array(
        'Детский мир' => array(
           'Детский мир', 'Детская одежда', 'Детская обувь', 
           'Детские коляски', 'Детские автокресла', 'Детская мебель',
           'Игрушки', 'Детский транспорт', 'Товары для кормления', 'Товары для школьников',
           'Прочие детские товары'),
        'Недвижимость' => array(
           'Недвижимость','Аренда квартир','Аренда комнат',
           'Аренда домов','Аренда земли','Аренда гаражей / Стоянок',
           'Ищу компаньона','Продажа квартир','Продажа комнат',
           'Продажа домов', 'Продажа земли','Продажа гаражей / Стоянок',
           'Аренда помещений','Продажа помещений','Прочая недвижимость',
           'Обмен недвижимости'),
        'Транспорт' => array(
          'Транспорт','Легковые автомобили','Мото','Автобусы',
          'Спецтехника','Грузовые автомобили','Сельхозтехника',
          'Водный транспорт','Воздушный транспорт','Запчасти / Аксессуары',
          'Прицепы','Другой транспорт','Авто / Мото услуги'),
        'Работа' => array(
          'Работа','Розничная торговля / Продажи','Транспорт / Логистика',
          'Строительство','Бары / Рестораны','Юриспруденция и Бухгалтерия',
          'Охрана / Безопасность','Домашний персонал','Красота / Фитнес / Спорт',
          'Туризм / Отдых / Развлечения','Образование','Культура / Искусство',
          'Медицина / Фармация','ИТ / Телеком / Компьютеры','Недвижимость',
          'Маркетинг / Реклама / Дизайн','Производство / Энергетика',
          'Cекретариат / АХО','Частичная занятость','Начало карьеры / Студенты',
          'Сервис и Быт','Другие сферы занятий'),
        'Животные' => array(
         'Животные','Собаки','Кошки','Аквариумистика',
         'Птицы','Грызуны','Рептилии','Сельхоз животные',
         'Животные даром','Зоотовары','Вязка','Бюро находок',
         'Другие животные'),
        'Дом и Сад' => array(
           'Дом и Сад','Канцтовары / Расходные материалы',
           'Мебель','Предметы интерьера','Строительство / Ремонт',
           'Инструменты','Комнатные Растения','Посуда / Кухонная утварь',
           'Садовый Инвентарь','Сад / Огород','Хозяйственный инвентарь / Бытовая химия',
           'Прочие товары для дома'),
         'Электроника' => array(
            'Электроника','Телефоны','Компьютеры',
            'Фото / Видео','Тв / Видеотехника','Аудиотехника',
            'Игры и Игровые приставки','Техника для дома',
            'Техника для кухни','Климатическое оборудование','Индивидуальный уход',
            'Аксессуары и комплектующие','Прочая электроника'),
          'Услуги / Бизнес' => array(
                'Услуги / Бизнес','Строительство / Ремонт / Уборка',
                'Финансовые услуги / Партнерство','Перевозки / Аренда транспорта',
                'Реклама / Полиграфия / Маркетинг / Интернет','Няни / Сиделки',
                'Сырьё / материалы','Красота / Здоровье','Оборудование','Образование / Спорт',
                'Услуги для животных','Продажа бизнеса','Развлечение / Искусство / Фото / Видео',
                'Туризм / Иммиграция','Услуги переводчиков / Набор текста','Авто / Мото услуги',
                'Обслуживание, Ремонт техники','Сетевой маркетинг','Юридические услуги',
                'Прокат товаров','Прочие услуги'),
            'Мода и Cтиль' => array(
                'Мода и Cтиль','Одежда/обувь','Для свадьбы',
                'Мода разное','Наручные часы','Аксессуары',
                'Подарки','Красота / Здоровье'),
            'Хобби, Отдых и Спорт' => array(
                'Хобби, Отдых и Спорт','Антиквариат / Коллекции',
                'Музыкальные инструменты','Другое','Спорт / Отдых',
                'Книги / Журналы','CD / DVD / Пластинки / Кассеты',
    'Билеты','Поиск попутчиков','Поиск групп / Музыкантов')
      );
```

Этим кодом я делаю выборку в зависимости от выбора значения в инпутах:

```
   if( isset($_GET["city"]) and isset($_GET["categor"]) ) {
    $city = htmlspecialchars($_GET["city"]);
    $city = trim ($city);
    $categor = htmlspecialchars($_GET["categor"]);
    $categor = trim ($categor);
    $where = array();
    $where[] = "city = '$city'";
    $where[] = "categor = '$categor'";
    if($city == 'Вся Беларусь' and $categor == 'Все категории')
        $res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `articles` ORDER BY `article_id` DESC LIMIT 12");
    else
    if($city == 'Вся Беларусь')
        $res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE categor IN ('" . implode("','", $categors[$categor]) . "') ORDER BY `article_id` DESC LIMIT 12");
    else
    if($categor == 'Все категории')
        $res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE city IN ('" . implode("','", $cities[$city]) . "') ORDER BY `article_id` DESC LIMIT 12");
    else
if (count($where) > 0 ) {
  $query = "SELECT *
            FROM `articles`
            WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $where) . "
            ORDER BY `article_id` DESC
            LIMIT 12";
} else {
  $query = "SELECT *
            FROM `articles`
            ORDER BY `article_id` DESC
            LIMIT 12";
}
$res = mysqli_query($db, $query);
}
```

Проблема в том что если я выберу не город а целую область и/или категорию то ничего не выводит, как это можно исправить? Выводит только по явному совпадению не учитывая вложенность в массив

Comment: Может все таки перенесете все справочники в БД. с ними же на порядок проще будет работать. И запрос всего один можно вместо выбора из кучи возможных вариантов, просто дописывать к нему дополнительные условия при заданном фильтре

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю как то так:

```
$where=array("1=1");
if($categor && $categor != 'Все категории') {
 if(array_key_exists($categor, $categors)) {
  $where[]="categor IN ('" . implode("','", $categors[$categor]) . "')";
 } else {
  $where[]="categor='$categor'";
 }
}
if($city && $city != 'Вся Беларусь') {
  if(array_key_exists($city, $cities)) {
   $where[]="city IN ('" . implode("','", $cities[$city]) . "')";
  } else {
   $where[]="city='$city'";
  }
}
$query = "SELECT *
            FROM `articles`
           WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $where) . "
           ORDER BY `article_id` DESC
           LIMIT 12";
```

Собственно все. Если ни одного фильтра не задано то условие запроса будет `"where 1=1"` которое всегда истинно и полностью равнозначно отсутствию `where` как такового.

P.S. Но перенести справочники в БД и отказаться от подстановки переменных в сам запрос (в пользу использования bind_param) все таки стоит...

Comment: Лучший) Спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Судя по коду, по-другому и быть не может, ведь в `SELECT` Вы передаете максимум 1 город здесь:

```
$where[] = "city = '$city'";
```

Не знаю, как у Вас организован инпут, потому сложно порекомендовать решение именно для Вас. Вариантов несколько, например:

1. Если из Вашего инпута придет название области, то из массива `область-город` берите список городов и добавляйте их в `$where`, примерно так:

   ```
   foreach $city in <список_городов_области> {
       $where[] = "city = '$city'";
   }
   ```

   Только учитывайте, что города в итоговом запросе надо объединять через `OR`, так как Вам надо будет выбрать или `city1`, или `city2`, или `city3` и т.д.
2. Либо организуйте форму таким образом, чтобы при выборе области в скрипт приходил список городов, потом их точно так же добавляете в `$where`.

P.S. Сейчас Ваш код работы с БД уязвим для инъекций. Рекомендую изучить вопрос о том, как от них защититься.